# Generar comentarios dentro de ng-repeat (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs

Buenos dias. Estoy intentando hacer una aplicacion de ejemplo en AngularJS. Intento anadir comentarios a los productos a traves del formulario que aparece en cada uno de los bloques de productos. El problema es que no se inserta el comentario, aparece en blanco. Tan solo funciona cuando lo inserto en la parte inicial del HTML

```js
   'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc function
 * @name yoAngApp.controller:AboutCtrl
 * @description
 * # AboutCtrl
 * Controller of the yoAngApp
 */
 angular.module('yoAngApp')
 .controller('AboutCtrl', function ($scope) {

  $scope.rate = 5;
  $scope.max = 10;
  $scope.isReadonly = false;

$scope.products = [
{
 img:"Image1",
 title:"Mobile1",
 content:"900",
 button: "Comentar producto",
 comments : [{name: "Name1", text: "Buen producto y diseno", star : 8}]
},
{
 img:"Image2",
 title:"Mobile2",
 content:"340",
 button: "Comentar producto",
 comments : [{name: "Name2", text: "Buen producto y diseno", star : 3}]
},
{
 img:"Image3",
 title:"Mobile3",
 content:"230",
 button: "Comentar producto",
 comments : [{name: "Name3", text: "Buen producto y diseno", star : 5}]
},
{
 img:"Image4",
 title:"Mobile4",
 content:"180",
 button: "Comentar producto",
 comments : [{name: "Name4", text: "Buen producto y diseno", star : 10}]
},
{
 img:"Image5",
 title:"Mobile5",
 content:"120",
 button: "Comentar producto",
 comments : [{name: "Name5", text: "Buen producto y diseno", star : 1}]
},
{
 img:"Image6",
 title:"Mobile6",
 content:"185",
 button: "Comentar producto",
 comments : [{name: "Name6", text: "Buen producto y diseno", star : 6}]
}

];

$scope.addComment = function ($index) {
    $scope.array = {name: $scope.username , text: $scope.usercomment , star: $scope.userrate};
    $scope.products[$index].comments.push($scope.array);
};



});
```

```html
<div class="row ">
 <div class="col-md-12">
 <div ng-repeat="product in products">
  <div class="col-md-4 div-block">
   <img class="img-responsive img-circle img-block" ng-src="{{product.img}}" style="margin:auto;">
   <h4>{{product.title}}</h4>
   <p>{{product.content | currency}}</p>
   <button ng-click="showComment = ! showComment">{{product.button}}</button>
   <h4> All comment </h4>
   <div class="col-md-12" ng-repeat="comment in product.comments" >
    <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color: #d3d3d3; margin-top: 2%; margin-bottom: 2%"> 
     <div class="col-md-12"><b>Name</b>: {{comment.name}}</div>
     <div class="col-md-12"><b>Comment</b>: {{comment.text}}</div>
     <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-bottom: 2%;"ng-init="x = comment.star"><uib-rating ng-model="x" readonly="true" max="10" aria-labelledby="default-rating"></uib-rating></div>

    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-12">
    <div ng-show="showComment" class="col-md-12" style="background-color: #e8e8e8;">
     <form ng-submit="addComment($index)" novalidate class="css-form">
      <h4>You comment</h4>
      <div class="col-md-12"><b>Name</b>: {{username}}</div>
      <div class="col-md-12"><b>Comment</b>: {{usercomment}}</div>
      <div class="col-md-12">Name</b>:<br/><input type="text" ng-model="username" required /><br /></div>
      <div class="col-md-12">Comment</b>:<br/><textarea ng-model="usercomment" /></textarea></div>
      <uib-rating ng-model="userrate" max="10" readonly="isReadonly" on-hover="hoveringOver(value)" on-leave="overStar = null" titles="['one','two','three']" aria-labelledby="default-rating"></uib-rating>
      <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-bottom: 2%;"><input type="submit" value="Save" /></div>
     </form>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: pero el "name" del comentario puedes visualizarlo ? no validaste si es un tema del diseño, alli veo que para los div del name, text defines col-md-12, no deberias repartir los valores, como ser col-md-4 a cada uno. Si inspeccionas el html desde la Developer Tools del browser puedes ver que el html del comentario no se genera?

Comment: Si se puede visualizar. Se generan perfectamente el nuevo bloque de comentario pero el contenido, tanto name como comentario esta vacio. 

Puedes ver un ejemplo aqui

http://oi63.tinypic.com/123440w.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El scope dentro de un ng-repeat no es el mismo que el scope del controlador. ng-repat crea un scope que desciende del scope del controlador por cada iteración. Las propiedades que declares en el scope dentro de ng-repat no son visibles por lo tanto para el scope del controlador.

Cambia la función addComent:

```
$scope.addComment = function ($index, name, text, star) {
    $scope.products[$index].comments.push({name: name, text: text, star: star});
};
```

Y cambia la llamada a la función:

```
<form ng-submit="addComment($index, username, usercomment, userrate)" novalidate class="css-form">
```

Comment: Perfecto, funcionó!. Muchas gracias por la explicación tan detallada.